Binary addition and declare the Register Flags X86
I'm trying to solve a question that asks me to find the sum of two Hexadecimal (16 base) values and then set the X86 Register Flags such as SF,ZF,PF,CF,AF, and OF.
First Value: A2FB
Second Value: CD1A
Step 1: I converted them to Binary (Base 2):
A2FA --> 1010 0010 1111 1011
CD1A --> 1100 1101 0001 1010
Step 2: Let's do Binary Addition
1010 0010 1111 1011

1100 1101 0001 1010

----------------------

1 0111 0000 0001 0101

Step 3: Go for Flags
My sum value was 16 bits; after sum, it's 17 bits, so the OF flag is 1 now.
SF = Sign Flag --> if the MSB is 1 so the SF is 1 and MSB is 0 the SF turned to 0. (In here my sum result in 16 bit is 0111 0000 0001 0101) so the MSB is 0 and my flag turned to 0.
ZF = Zero Flag --> If the bits are 0 my ZF flag turned to 1 but if not it's gonna be 0. (In my case it's a non-zero result so the ZF flag is 0.
PF = Parity Flag --> The 8 first bits from right to left which is (00010101) - (in this case I need to count 1 which is 3 here so it's odd and I put 0 for the PF flag)
CF = Carry Flag --> If there's a Carry or Borrow from the MSB it's 1 and if not it's 0. (In my case my MSB has no Carry so it's gonna be 0)
AF = Auxiliary Carry --> Carry from the 3rd bit to the 4th bit during addition or borrow from the 4th bit. (In my case my 3rd bit is 1 and 1 so 1 + 1 = 10 and it has a Carry to the 4th bit so it's gonna be 1 value for the AF flag)
In total:
OF = 1
SF = 0
ZF = 0
PF = 0
CF = 0
AF = 1

I'd to know if I made any mistake and I appreciate any help or tips. Thank you for reading.

In third line first value is "A2FB" but in fifth line is "A2FA" .

We discourage "please check whether my answer is correct" questions, as only "yes/no" answers are possible, which won't help you or future visitors. See here and here. Can you edit your post to ask about a specific conceptual issue you're uncertain about? As a rule of thumb, a good conceptual question should be useful even to someone who isn't looking at the problem you happen to be working on. If you just need someone to check your work, you might seek out a friend, classmate, or teacher.

Find a simulator. Check the flag definitions and the instruction definition.

The MSB did have a carry, that's where the lone 1 at the top of your result comes from.

(@zkutch: the binary in the 5th line is A2FB(base 16) again.)
